# Получение курсов евро

Tags: php, xml

Подскажите, где можно получать курсы валют, сейчас получаю с сайта cbr.ru XML файл, но порой вылетает ошибка, PHP что не удалось открыть стрим.

как правильно подключаться к cbr?

или дайте ссылку на другой ресурс, где можно получать курсы!

```
function getCurs($moneyCode){  
// создаем объект для работы с XML  
$xml = new DOMDocument();  
// ссылка на сайт банка  
$url = 'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=' . date('d.m.Y');  
// получаем xml с курсами всех валют  
if ($xml->load($url)){  
    // массив для хранения курсов валют  
    $result = array();   
    // разбираем xml  
    $root = $xml->documentElement;  
    // берем все теги 'Valute' и их содержимое  
    $items = $root->getElementsByTagName('Valute');  
    // переберем теги 'Valute' по одному  
    foreach ($items as $item){  
    // получаем код валюты  
        $code = $item->getElementsByTagName('CharCode')->item(0)->nodeValue;  
        // получаем значение курса валюты, относительно рубля  
        $value = $item->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item(0)->nodeValue;  
        // записываем в массив, предварительно заменив запятую на точку  
        $result[$code] = str_replace(',', '.', $value);  
    }  
    // возвращаем значение курса, для запрошенной валюты  
    return $result[$moneyCode];  
}else{  
    // если не получили xml возвращаем false  
    return false;  
}
```

}

Comment: дак приложите код, как вы их оттуда забираете.

Comment: @teran добавил код

Comment: Не ищите ошибку в своём коде. Проблема в криворукости программистов cbr.

Comment: @KAGGDesign , так и мой вопрос в том что, где взять замену тогда? раз они такие кривые?

Comment: ну так заверните все в try-catch и если не удалось забрать, повторите попытку позже. Вряд ли курс будет меняться по сто раз на день.

Comment: Если при получении XML упорно возникает ошибка, есть подозрение на бан, то откройте тот же самый адрес через браузер (например, консольный браузер lynx). Будет несколько редиректов, вам покажут XML в браузере, а потом и скрипт PHP заработает.

Comment: Для таких вещей обычно пишут скрипты в отдельных файлах, которые запускают по cron'у, ибо нечего спамить чужие сервера.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ЦБ РФ не любит когда вы делаете больше чем сколько-то запросов в день. Ваш скрипт делает запрос к сервисам ЦБ РФ каждый раз когда кто-то открывает страницу. Если у вас хотя бы 1000 просмотров страниц в день, то это значит 1000 обращений к сервису ЦБ РФ. Этого количества вполне может быть достаточно чтобы забанить вас.

Если даже у вас нет никаких посетителей, на том же сервере что и ваш могут быть другие сайты, у которых такой же скрипт. Или даже хуже: автор встречал случаи когда для конвертации валют в прайс-листе для каждой строчки и для каждой валюты делался запрос за курсами валют. В прайс-листе было под тысячу позиций, а это значит для каждого скаченного прайс-листа к сайту ЦБ РФ делалось *несколько тысяч запросов*. Будь я вебмастером сайта ЦБ РФ, я бы тоже за такое внёс любые IP в чёрный список!

Так или иначе, попасть в чёрный список сайта ЦБ РФ очень просто. В этом случае вы будете получать такую ошибку:

```
failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached
```

Ошибка возникает потому что сайт ЦБ РФ передаёт вам куки и просит их сохранить и использовать при следующем запросе. То есть, вам придётся эмулировать браузер. И даже если вы будете эмулировать браузер, с вашим скриптом вы всё равно можете попасть в бан, из которого эмуляцией браузера не выбраться: все запросы к сайту ЦБ РФ будут сбрасываться. Как ни крути, *вашим скриптом нельзя пользоваться.*

Частично нивелировать проблему можно [если кешировать данные после получения](https://php.ru/forum/threads/parsing-kursa-valjut.47835/#post-521922) как минимум на несколько часов. Всё равно они обновляются лишь пару раз в день. Это сработает если это ваш выделенный сервер и никто больше кроме вас не использует похожие скрипты, засыпающие ЦБ РФ запросами.

```
function getCBRRates()
{
    $xml_daily_file = __DIR__.'/daily.xml';

    // кеш на четыре часа
    if (!is_file($xml_daily_file) || filemtime($xml_daily_file) < time() - 7200) {
        if ($xml_daily = file_get_contents('http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp')) {
            file_put_contents($xml_daily_file, $xml_daily);
        }
    }

    $result = array();
    foreach (simplexml_load_file($xml_daily_file) as $el) {
        $result[strval($el->CharCode)] = (float) strtr($el->Value, ',', '.');
    }

    return $result;
}

echo getCBRRates()['USD'];
```

Ещё лучше будет показывать данные прямо на стороне клиента, минуя серверную часть. Данные в подходящем формате можно взять с известного зеркала с курсами ЦБ РФ. Этот сайт хорошо себя зарекомендовал давней и надёжной работой.

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", function(data) {
    $('#EUR').text(data.Valute.EUR.Value.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

€1 = <span id="EUR"></span> руб.
```

Аналогично можно показывать курсы других валют, показывать изменение курса относительно прошлого дня, и так далее.

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", function(data) {
    console.log(data.Valute.EUR);
    console.log(data.Valute.USD);
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Если вы посмотрите, там есть все необходимые данные и даже отсылки к архиву курсов валют.

Comment: Все это красиво изложено, но я получал ошибку на малопосещаемом сайте, размещённом на VPS. То есть ни о каких банах за запросы речи не было. Просто несколько дней подряд плагин не работал, а потом вдруг опять начинал работать. На сайте и сервере вообще ничего не трогали.

Comment: Если ваш плагин не работал, так это именно из-за бана ЦБ РФ.

Comment: На сервере у клиента 6 сайтов, только один имеет отношение к вопросу (запрашивает курсы). Плагин установлен вот этот https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/ более 30 тысяч активных установок. Согласно документации и опциям, плагин кеширует запросы. В опциях задано обновление 1 раз в час. Я не проверял, но сильно сомневаюсь, что плагин с таких количеством активных установок делает не 24 запроса в сутки, а 1000+. К тому же при посещаемости в 100 визитов.

Comment: Не важно. Если вы делаете более 10 запросов курсов в день, то вы уже делаете излишнее количество. Курсы ЦБ РФ обновляются ровно два раза в день по рабочим дням, и не обновляются вообще по выходным.

Answer (score 5):

Предложу один из вариантов смеха ради)) Однако если его реализовать, то он будет самым лучшим.

Для этого нужно:

1) открыть реальный брокерский счет и установить терминал Quik на сервер Windows (или виртуальную машину Windows)

2) Через Lua (или Lua + C++) организовать выгрузку данных по валюте выбранной и сохранять данные куда угодно, хоть в MmoryMapedFile.

3) Из источника, просто транслировать на сайт.

из плюсов - не сломается и бесплатно (за минусом оплата сервера для установки терминала) к тому же курс с торгов берется напрямую (но он не будет обменным.)

Из минусов - много времени и сил уйдет на создание этой стыковки))

Comment: Открытие брокерского счёта что-то стоит? Где это можно сделать? Подробней бы.

Comment: @sanmai Нет, это совершенно бесплатно. Вы просто приходите к брокеру (к примеру Открытие брокер - у них можно даже через сайт открыть счет https://open-broker.ru/) Далее Вам по надоедают немного телефонными звонками но вы не обязаны поплнять счет и прочие... Позже просто скачиваете терминал quik с личного кабинета и начинаете программировать. Вот несколько полезных ресурсов по стыковке квика с С++ и по работе api Lua: https://quikluacsharp.ru/ и официальный форум создателей ОП Quik: https://forum.quik.ru/forum10/

Answer (score 0):

Работающий плагин, забирающий данные с cbr.ru, периодически перестает работать на несколько дней. Известные мне альтернативы, которые должны работать (но я не пробовал):

http://www.google.com/finance/converter

http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange

http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables

Comment: Не думаю, что понял, про плагин? это объяснение почему у цб не робит? иль что?
1. не пускает меня
2. вроде выдает, но как Я должен переводить это в рубли?
3. выдает вроде как для Украины
4. выдает 404 ошибку

Comment: Неважно, какой плагин. Имеет большое кол-во установок, но то работает, то не работает с ЦБ. Это говорит о том, что проблема на сайте ЦБ. Остальные сайты не проверял, не знаю.

Comment: ну то что это проблема ЦБ мы сами поняли сразу, но мы не можем ни как придумать либо нормальный костыль, либо другой подходящий источник курсов не можем найти

Comment: Не понимаю, что вас не устраивает в примитивном файле от ecb: http://take.ms/Syvc7

Comment: меня не устраивает то, что его курс не совпадает с курсом ЦБР