# Как получить курсы валют по api?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть ли бесплатные способы получения курсов валют.
на этой странице многие методы не работают
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282578/currency-conversion-using-php
Может быть есть готовые библиотеки?
Нужно конвертировать цены в html-таблице по клюку кнопки на нужной валюте.
Основные валюты: `usd, euro, gbr, aud`
Интересуют способы как на php так и на javascript

Comment: вопрос то в чем? где взять - на сайте центробанка.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760270/

Answer (score 1):

Поверим гуглу.

1. Composer: composer require nabarabane/cbr:~1.0
2. Github: [github](https://github.com/nabarabane/cbr/)

```
$handler = new CurrencyDaily();
    $result = $handler
        ->setDate('20/07/2015') // Опционально, дата в формате "d/m/Y"
        ->setCodes(['USD', 'EUR']) // Опционально, фильтр по кодам валют
        ->request() // Выполнение запроса
        ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Может кто-то ещё будет искать курсы с банков и обменников Украины вот api KursToday https://github.com/pavlovich-app/KursToday-API. И пример работы на сайте в бегущей строке - https://www.insite.top/